# One form two submit

Tags: php, forms, session, submit

I have one form. One that form I have two things: Some input fields for Name, adress, tel... And an empty 'img' tag.

What I want to do:

From the same Form: I wish the user to be able either to upload his ID picture - so it is loaded in the img tag (via a MySql table). <-- one submit. Or to send the whole form filled; input fields + image. <-- second submit.

The idea being Having 2 "triggers" passing a different variables to a tiers php page; which will evaluate that variable and do what it is supposed to do with that variable.

I found some code here on the forum. And it works well to launch 2 different web pages. But the **input type="image"** doesn't seem to pass the **$_Session[ ]** variables.

Here is a part of the code HTML:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" name="form1" method="post"     action="select.php">
    <input type="image" src="/graphic files/MiniFolder24.png" alt="submit" name="Upload" value="Upload">
    <input type="image" src="/graphic files/Floppy.jpg" alt="submit" name="Record" value="Record">
```

My select.php

```
<?php
   ob_start();
   session_start();
   if($_POST["Record"]) {
     header('Location: record_in_db.php');
   }

   if($_POST["Upload"]) {
     header('Location: browse.html');
   }
```

?>

I have no problem with browse.html but my record_in_db.php don't get the **$_SESSION[ ]** variables.

Beginning of record_in_db.php:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  session_start();
  $PersoNum = $_SESSION['Day'];
  $PersoNum .= $_SESSION['Month'];
  $PersoNum .= $_SESSION['Year'];
  $PersoNum .= $_SESSION['FødNr'];

  $P_N_Day= $_SESSION['Day'];
  $P_N_Month = $_SESSION['Month'];
  $P_N_Year = $_SESSION['Year'];
  $P_N_Number = $_SESSION['FødNr'];
  $Photo_Path = $_SESSION['Target_File'];
```

Only $Photo_path contains the variable passed from another php file via browse.html

I'm scratching my head quite a bit. It just helps me lose my few remaining hair but no light so far.

Any light from the ouside? What am I doing wrong?

Thanx.

The **$_SESSION['Day'];** ect refer to input text fields

Comment: Where you put values into sessions?

Comment: $_POST["Upload"] it should be $_FILES["Upload"]) ;

Comment: @panther The session values are taken from input text field in the calling page.

Comment: @saty that part works well.

Comment: where is your calling page??

Comment: check for error reporting...

Comment: @saty Same directory as the other pages.

Comment: @HassanMurtaza No error report. Just my Session variables are empty...